# Problem with translation for zoom after key moving

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I can move on a graph with the help of keys (right, left) and mouse. If I use only mouse then zoom is work correct otherwise doesn't. My code:

```
container.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate[0] + ', 0) scale(' + d3.event.scale + ', 1)');
```

In begin:

[image]

I pressed -> and I wanted to zoom [-1;-2] and I moved cursor to the [-1;-2].

[image]

But the graph was moved to the [9;6]:

[image]

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work correctly? In what browsers did you test it? Also, can you add screenshots? Can you add more context?

Comment: @dagelf, d3.event hasn't been change when I press arrows. When I zoom after key pressing I get wrong translate values (from last zoom), but after zooming or moving (with the help mouse drag) I have correct translate values. I use google chrome.

Comment: @dagelf I have added more details and images.